# Open chat and send message with tg://

Tags: telegram, sendmessage, php-telegram-bot

I want open a telegram chat and send a designated message to a designated chat_id

I tried this but it just opens chat without message : `tg://openmessage?user_id=1315949751&msg?text=AnyText`

Is there a way to do that ?